# need to alter a dropdownlist after it's been databound to an sql data source

Tags: asp.net

Ok so I've got my Drop down list databound to an sql data source, now I need to change the data in a few of the fields before it gets displayed.  I've been messing with this all morning and I can't find anything useful, this is what I've got so far and it's clearly not working...

```
Protected Sub ddlBookType_DataBound(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ddlBookType.DataBound
    'ddlBookType.Items.Insert(0, "Any")
    Dim i As Integer
    For i = 0 To ddlBookType.Items.Count - 1
        If ddlBookType.Items(i).Attributes.Equals("mod_cook") Then
            ddlBookType.Items(i).Text.Replace("mod_cook", "Modern Cooking")
        End If
    Next
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hey I've just done it in C# and converted it into VB (I hope it's right).

Here's the code (

```
Protected Sub ddlBookType_DataBound(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    Dim ddlBookType As DropDownList = DirectCast(sender, DropDownList)
    For Each item As ListItem In ddlBookType.Items
        If item.Text = "mod_cook" Then
            item.Text = "Modern Cooking"
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

And here's the original C# code

```
protected void ddlBookType_DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DropDownList ddlBookType = (DropDownList)sender;
    foreach (ListItem item in ddlBookType.Items)
    {
        if (item.Text == "mod_cook")
        {
            item.Text = "Modern Cooking";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice try man but it's still not changing the value, man I am starting to regret doing this in vb, but if it works in c# maybe I just have to mess with it a bit...

Comment: Hey I just noticed I hooked into the wrong event on the sample above. Change it to the DataBound event, I've updated my answer.